# React Native - Firebase with ListView

Tags: listview, typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to display data from Firebase in Listview in React Native.

I succeed to display static data like "hey", but I don't know how I can display Firebase data. My database is like that : users > email (for example in order to display email).

I did firebaseConfig and two .js files :

1. index.ios.js :

Code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, ListView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Row from './Row';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  separator: {
    flex: 1,
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    backgroundColor: '#8E8E8E',
  },
});

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xx",
  authDomain: "xx",
  databaseURL: "xx",
  storageBucket: "<your-storage-bucket>",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
        renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
      />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

2. Row.js :

Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 12,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

const Row = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text style={styles.text}>
    "Hey"
    </Text>
  </View>
);

export default Row;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fetch/query firebase for your data. This is typically done in the constructor or `componentWillMount` lifecycle method.

Something along the lines of:

```
firebaseApp.database().ref().child(`${<someUserPath>}/username`).once("value", (snapshot) => {
    this.setState({ username: snapshot.val() });
  });
```

After you have your desired data, you then pass it down to the `ListView` as props like this:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows([this.state.username])} />
```